# Github windows HTTP failed error

Tags: git, github

I have installed Github for windows and when trying to clone the django repo which i have forked on github, i get an error

```
error: Failed connect to github.com:8080; No error while accessing https://github.com/django   /django.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have a proper working wifi internet connection...have logged in via the application..still after failing it asks to check my internet connection

Comment: hmm... not sure if this is a suitable post here...

Comment: maybe i missed something???doesnt look like a bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry..it was a foolish mistake...
I had previously set a proxy for my institue

I simply unset it using

```
git config –global –unset http.proxy
```